# Imagick SVG to JPG error no decode delegate

Tags: php, svg, jpeg, imagick

I have tried many different solutions, but cannot use Imagick::readImageBlob, any help would be appreciated.

Error message:

```
Caught exception: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/364
```

Code:

```
$svg = file_get_contents($this->svg);
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($svg);
//...
```

SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
    <svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="928" height="933" id="parent">

        <image width="928" height="933" xlink:href="image.jpg" ></image>

        <path id="path1" fill="none" d="M100,656.5c-105.1-200.5-28.1-448,172-553s447.5-27.5,552.6,173s28.1,448-172,553 S205.1,856.9,100,656.5z"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle">
            <textPath xlink:href="#path1" startOffset="33.3333%">
                <tspan>top</tspan>
            </textPath>
        </text>

        <path id="path2" fill="none" d="M121.8,264.8C10.2,453.3,72.2,696.3,260.3,807.7s431,48.9,542.6-139.5 s49.5-431.5-138.5-542.8S233.3,76.4,121.8,264.8z"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle">
        <textPath xlink:href="#path2" startOffset="33.3333%">
            <tspan>bund</tspan></textPath>
        </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Is SVG a listed format in `\Imagick::queryformats();` ? You probably don't have an appropriate library to read SVG images installed such as RSVG.

Comment: I see that SVG is not on the list, where can I find the right install files for RSVG

Comment: You haven't said what your system is. On centos it would be `yum install rsvg` probably.

Comment: sorry about that, it's an ubuntu server, but I find that if I added the missing items to imagick it worked,

Comment: What was missing? I'm having this exact issue. Trying to base64 decdoe an svg to I can convert it to png

Answer (score 10):

For me these deps were missing (ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick1-dev libmagickcore-dev libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
```

The expected output:

```
identify -list format | grep SVG
     MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
      SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.13)
     SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.13)
```

Comment: The shell renders the correct output from `identify -list format | grep SVG`, however I still received the `no decode delegate for this image format`... thoughts?

Comment: The above solution worked for me except libmagickcore-6.q16-2 this one. This lib has been obsolete.

Answer (score 7):

After having tried by @Native Coder and @karser answers my SVG was still generating the same no decode delegate error. It worked after I added `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` as the opening line of my SVG content. Worth checking your XML is valid as well.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks! (Ubuntu 18, PHP 7.4)

Comment: My svg contains that xml line :(

Comment: Maybe check there is no extra white space around it?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this issue by installing inkscape.

```
apt-get install inkscape
```

See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63175979/751202

Comment: Didn't work for me, unfortunately (Ubuntu 20.04). Thus, doesn't seem to be a universal solution.

Comment: Installing inkscape worked for me in two environments.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ubuntu 20.04, I ran the below command that installed the [`libmagickcore-6`](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/imagemagick) package.

This package adds support for SVG, WMF, OpenEXR, DjVu and Graphviz to MagickCore.
There are a few different versions, for instance, one of the versions is compiled for a channel depth of 16 bits with high dynamic range (Q16HDRI).

```
 sudo apt install libmagickcore-6*
```

With the above command, it seems like I installed *all* the different versions. Not sure if that's the best slash most efficient way, but it did take care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone reading this in the future, I had this exact same issue. The problem was that I was missing libxml2 and librsvg2-bin.

Answer (score 0):

Docker image alpine, work for me:

```
RUN apk add --update imagemagick imagemagick-libs imagemagick-dev \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried all solution above without result and i finally installed inkscape (which is used by imagemagick) and it works perfectly now !

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```