# Imagick SVG - no decode delegate for this image format

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I got a SVG which I have to read via readImageBlob() on the server-side. This works with certain SVGs, but with others I receive following http response:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"420","status":"500","title":"Internal Server Error","detail":"no decode delegate for this image format `\u0027 @ error\/blob.c\/BlobToImage\/353","meta":{"trace":[{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/custom\/plugins\/TextureGenerator\/src\/Service\/ImageGenerator.php","line":368,"function":"readImageBlob","class":"Imagick","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/custom\/plugins\/TextureGenerator\/src\/Service\/ImageGenerator.php","line":391,"function":"drawImage","class":"TextureGenerator\\Service\\ImageGenerator","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/custom\/plugins\/TextureGenerator\/src\/Service\/ImageGenerator.php","line":54,"function":"drawLogo","class":"TextureGenerator\\Service\\ImageGenerator","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/custom\/plugins\/TextureGenerator\/src\/Controller\/ImageController.php","line":76,"function":"generateImage","class":"TextureGenerator\\Service\\ImageGenerator","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php","line":156,"function":"generateTexture","class":"TextureGenerator\\Controller\\ImageController","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpKernel.php","line":78,"function":"handleRaw","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/Kernel.php","line":199,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/SubRequestHandler.php","line":85,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":479,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\SubRequestHandler","type":"::"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":452,"function":"forward","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":346,"function":"fetch","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/http-kernel\/HttpCache\/HttpCache.php","line":224,"function":"lookup","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/HttpKernel.php","line":178,"function":"handle","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpCache\\HttpCache","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/HttpKernel.php","line":81,"function":"doHandle","class":"Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"},{"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/public\/index.php","line":77,"function":"handle","class":"Shopware\\Core\\HttpKernel","type":"-\u003E"}],"file":"\/var\/www\/html\/custom\/plugins\/TextureGenerator\/src\/Service\/ImageGenerator.php","line":368}}]}
```

I noticed that it seems to work with SVGs using a path only, but fails as soon as there is a shape like rect or polygon inside.

Here is an example where it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   version="1.1"
   id="svg12709"
   xml:space="preserve"
   width="1066.6667"
   height="1066.6667"
   viewBox="0 0 1066.6667 1066.6667"
   sodipodi:docname="squirrel-silhouette-pdv.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.1.2 (b8e25be833, 2022-02-05)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs
     id="defs12713"><clipPath
       clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="clipPath12723"><path
         d="M 0,800 H 800 V 0 H 0 Z"
         id="path12721" /></clipPath></defs><sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview12711"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.77906244"
     inkscape:cx="533.33337"
     inkscape:cy="533.33337"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1018"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="g12715" /><g
     id="g12715"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     inkscape:label="squirrel-silhouette-pdv"
     transform="matrix(1.3333333,0,0,-1.3333333,0,1066.6667)"><g
       id="g12717"><g
         id="g12719"
         clip-path="url(#clipPath12723)"><path
           d="m 617.938,557.31 -0.206,-0.965 0.67,-0.219 1.226,-3.157 0.696,-0.143 0.541,2.477 1.59,-0.528 -0.894,2.303 c 4.226,4.343 6.375,8.074 7.282,11.193 2.532,-5.436 5.683,-12.239 8.815,-19.014 l 14.866,-3.061 c -0.037,1.617 -0.282,3.131 -0.618,4.41 2.055,-0.133 4.573,-2.486 7.052,-5.734 l 9.169,-1.888 c -4.441,12.46 -13.832,23.655 -17.624,27.848 0.419,0.097 0.843,0.142 1.294,0.142 5.597,0 11.078,-7.643 11.135,-7.72 l 2.985,-4.233 v 5.185 c 0,8.653 -6.201,14.88 -12.197,20.901 -4.677,4.704 -9.521,9.56 -11.644,15.626 -0.676,1.938 -0.74,2.858 -0.715,3.244 2.214,-0.251 8.46,-4.948 13.157,-9.31 l 3.274,-3.042 -0.521,4.438 c -1.82,15.479 -11.786,21.886 -20.58,27.547 -2.97,1.907 -5.72,3.681 -7.972,5.655 l -25.84,-53.126 c 5.984,-3.883 11.445,-9.82 15.059,-18.829"
           style="fill:#b4291e;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12725" /><path
           d="m 644.746,630.43 3.197,-1.84 -0.772,3.615 c -1.218,5.689 -5.048,10.267 -10.132,14.163 l -4.791,-9.849 c 4.802,-1.903 10.063,-4.688 12.498,-6.089"
           style="fill:#b4291e;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12727" /><path
           d="m 640.883,310.057 c -1.526,6.053 -3.16,12.244 -4.9,18.561 l -31.749,-21.863 z"
           style="fill:#023dcc;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12729" /><path
           d="m 656.867,191.087 c 0.791,17.106 -0.456,36.782 -3.738,58.987 l -58.193,-35.145 z"
           style="fill:#0056c8;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12731" /><path
           d="m 604.234,306.755 -9.298,-91.826 58.193,35.145 c -2.703,18.286 -6.781,38.282 -12.246,59.983 z"
           style="fill:#006ad4;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12733" /><path
           d="m 635.983,328.618 c -2.37,8.611 -4.937,17.462 -7.707,26.561 l -0.038,0.129 -0.064,0.128 c -0.014,0.039 -0.206,0.418 -0.509,1.093 0.341,0.013 0.676,0.097 0.972,0.264 1.389,0.778 1.595,3.044 0.463,5.051 -1.094,1.942 -3.037,2.932 -4.413,2.289 -4.156,12.146 -9.38,34.855 0.604,54.297 l 1.943,3.796 -3.988,-1.506 c -0.68,-0.253 -3.096,-1.191 -6.023,-2.668 L 604.234,306.755 Z"
           style="fill:#5998c4;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12735" /><path
           d="m 592.233,107.765 c 20.468,1.048 36.38,9.044 47.321,23.808 10.357,13.984 16.124,33.865 17.313,59.514 l -61.931,23.842 z"
           style="fill:#0063c3;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12737" /><path
           d="m 620.094,551.771 0.23,1.055 -0.696,0.143 z"
           style="fill:#b28e77;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12739" /><path
           d="m 667.385,530.419 3.351,-7.411 -0.213,8.132 c -0.103,3.956 -1.011,7.961 -2.396,11.844 l -9.169,1.888 c 3.256,-4.266 6.442,-10.078 8.427,-14.453"
           style="fill:#b28e77;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12741" /><path
           d="m 644.359,534.729 0.825,-1.8 1.621,1.144 c 4.558,3.233 5.814,8.008 5.719,12.123 l -14.866,3.061 c 2.333,-5.049 4.655,-10.083 6.701,-14.528"
           style="fill:#b28e77;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12743" /><path
           d="m 604.234,306.755 12.989,111.297 c -5.12,-2.584 -11.812,-6.824 -13.547,-11.974 -1.672,3.468 -4.195,10.467 -5.584,20.001 -0.612,4.194 -1.05,9.205 -0.965,14.724 l -61.473,-30.598 z"
           style="fill:#6ec9cd;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12745" /><path
           d="m 581.425,569.313 c 0.216,1.341 0.694,7.761 -8.732,13.691 1.248,0.084 2.684,0.148 4.266,0.148 6.867,0 16.979,-1.212 25.92,-7.013 l 25.84,53.126 c -2.041,1.789 -3.675,3.741 -4.676,6.112 -0.926,2.219 -0.559,2.811 -0.54,2.837 0.064,0.109 0.411,0.289 1.248,0.289 1.841,0 4.585,-0.83 7.497,-1.984 l 4.791,9.849 c -6.17,4.729 -14.191,8.45 -21.668,11.917 -2.271,1.053 -4.509,2.089 -6.596,3.116 l -102.179,-26.86 z"
           style="fill:#c32500;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12747" /><path
           d="m 627.736,665.581 4.928,-1.776 -2.321,3.265 -3.925,-1.031 c 0.813,-0.277 1.289,-0.448 1.318,-0.458"
           style="fill:#c32500;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12749" /><path
           d="m 548.678,721.923 -3.949,0.758 -0.774,-1.789 z"
           style="fill:#c10600;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12751" /><path
           d="m 608.775,661.401 c -5.769,2.84 -10.379,5.603 -11.314,8.4 -0.115,0.354 -0.283,0.99 -0.057,1.3 0.102,0.141 0.752,0.836 3.672,0.836 7.469,0 21.074,-4.44 25.342,-5.898 l 3.925,1.031 -0.716,1.006 c -11.773,16.573 -26.318,18.361 -39.152,19.938 -8.916,1.093 -16.618,2.039 -22.195,7.623 -2.225,2.219 -3.062,4.079 -2.496,5.507 1.892,4.773 17.306,7.011 26.57,7.301 l 6.909,0.212 -6.267,2.921 c -6.723,3.14 -14.094,4.657 -22.529,4.657 -9.449,0 -18.334,-1.897 -26.182,-3.576 -1.484,-0.316 -2.912,-0.621 -4.281,-0.898 l -33.408,-77.22 z"
           style="fill:#c10600;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12753" /><path
           d="m 483.975,102.218 c 5.53,0.74 10.34,1.974 14.814,3.763 9.289,3.712 16.867,9.882 23.141,18.825 5.27,-2.636 24.435,-11.643 46.591,-15.447 l -69.287,98.983 z"
           style="fill:#0074ce;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12755" /><path
           d="m 499.234,208.342 69.287,-98.983 c 6.182,-1.061 12.596,-1.717 19.007,-1.717 1.595,0 3.161,0.043 4.705,0.123 l 2.703,107.164 z"
           style="fill:#007fd1;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12757" /><path
           d="m 597.127,440.803 c 0.139,8.988 1.667,19.326 6.111,29.697 l 1.565,3.629 -3.674,-1.454 c -0.619,-0.245 -14.064,-5.713 -19.004,-19.126 -1.879,3.319 -4.762,9.18 -6.588,16.617 -3.859,15.658 -1.506,30.544 7.006,44.234 l 2.161,3.474 -3.962,-1.017 c -0.111,-0.03 -1.421,-0.369 -3.361,-1.094 L 535.654,410.205 Z"
           style="fill:#abc38c;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12759" /><path
           d="m 498.647,731.482 -1.491,-0.13 0.053,-0.534 z"
           style="fill:#c60800;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12761" /><path
           d="m 540.004,711.761 c -3.803,-0.771 -7.135,-1.327 -9.82,-1.327 -2.073,0 -3.584,0.334 -4.62,1.022 -0.914,0.61 -1.416,1.203 -1.344,1.589 0.424,2.22 8.934,5.5 16.616,7.167 l 3.119,0.68 0.774,1.789 -3.931,0.754 c -4.503,0.868 -8.981,1.305 -13.304,1.305 -11.902,0 -21.451,-3.322 -29.039,-6.707 l 8.141,-83.492 z"
           style="fill:#c60800;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12763" /><path
           d="m 535.654,410.205 41.727,105.558 c -2.213,-0.826 -5.246,-2.154 -8.264,-4.097 -5.32,-3.416 -8.814,-7.598 -10.346,-12.319 -0.9,2.946 -1.812,6.799 -2.199,11.18 -1.152,13.112 2.837,24.318 11.85,33.299 l 2.521,2.509 -23.86,1.955 c 0.348,1.981 1.255,5.559 3.545,9.136 0.41,0.638 0.854,1.24 1.313,1.823 l -84.091,2.064 z"
           style="fill:#c8c46d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12765" /><path
           d="m 499.234,208.342 95.702,6.587 -89.502,85.24 z"
           style="fill:#0097de;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12767" /><path
           d="m 594.936,214.929 9.298,91.826 -98.8,-6.586 z"
           style="fill:#008dde;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12769" /><path
           d="m 505.434,300.169 98.8,6.586 -68.58,103.45 z"
           style="fill:#189fe2;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12771" /><path
           d="m 467.85,561.313 84.091,-2.064 c 4.678,5.928 11.924,8.945 21.588,8.945 1.918,0 3.964,-0.128 6.061,-0.366 l 1.441,-0.167 0.348,1.408 c 0.006,0.03 0.025,0.115 0.046,0.244 l -74.829,65.228 z"
           style="fill:#ce630c;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12773" /><path
           d="m 355.101,507.068 44.17,-121.272 68.579,175.517 z"
           style="fill:#dae263;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12775" /><path
           d="m 417.869,167.659 54.722,-66.26 c 4.139,0.088 7.908,0.354 11.384,0.819 l 15.259,106.124 z"
           style="fill:#008ad9;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12777" /><path
           d="M 535.654,410.205 399.271,385.796 505.434,300.169 Z"
           style="fill:#75e0e0;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12779" /><path
           d="M 467.85,561.313 399.271,385.796 535.654,410.205 Z"
           style="fill:#afdf7c;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12781" /><path
           d="m 390.859,698.146 3.944,9.212 -6.678,-7.475 c -11.077,-12.372 -16.88,-28.766 -20.542,-43.182 l 16.715,17.92 c 0.3,6.579 3.771,17.018 6.561,23.525"
           style="fill:#df2200;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12783" /><path
           d="m 355.727,651.962 0.232,7.675 -3.358,-6.91 c -3.37,-6.939 -5.138,-12.924 -6.02,-18.539 l 9.253,9.92 c -0.149,2.73 -0.181,5.443 -0.107,7.854"
           style="fill:#df2200;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12785" /><path
           d="m 399.496,690.913 28.793,30.865 c -14.648,-6.175 -23.059,-19.263 -28.793,-30.865"
           style="fill:#df2200;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12787" /><path
           d="m 417.869,167.659 81.365,40.683 6.2,91.827 z"
           style="fill:#009be2;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12789" /><path
           d="m 336.116,334.652 81.753,-166.993 87.565,132.51 z"
           style="fill:#16b5ec;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12791" /><path
           d="m 498.455,718.033 c -2.238,-0.999 -4.309,-2.003 -6.215,-2.929 -5.262,-2.561 -9.419,-4.574 -12.828,-4.574 -1.326,-0.007 -2.496,0.315 -3.564,0.964 -2.252,1.358 -2.182,2.542 -2.161,2.928 0.231,4.142 10.176,10.241 16.391,13.104 l 7.131,3.292 -0.053,0.534 -7.914,-0.693 c -25.404,-2.232 -40.529,-14.153 -50.539,-22.04 -5.43,-4.285 -9.727,-7.669 -13.221,-7.669 -0.43,0 -0.849,0.052 -1.267,0.154 -1.871,0.464 -2.084,1.288 -2.161,1.596 -0.94,3.635 6.638,12.66 12.313,17.91 l 5.185,4.806 -6.775,-2.02 c -1.56,-0.464 -3.05,-1.012 -4.488,-1.618 l -28.793,-30.865 c -1.561,-3.16 -2.928,-6.211 -4.166,-8.979 -3.037,-6.788 -5.906,-13.201 -8.402,-13.201 -0.077,0 -0.154,0.006 -0.231,0.019 -0.779,0.109 -1.3,0.47 -1.693,1.165 -0.599,1.066 -0.796,2.71 -0.706,4.704 l -16.715,-17.92 c -1.454,-5.719 -2.57,-11.128 -3.544,-15.849 -0.926,-4.493 -1.941,-9.414 -2.884,-12.088 l 145.441,5.777 z"
           style="fill:#dc2b00;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12793" /><path
           d="m 355.834,644.108 -9.253,-9.92 c -0.322,-2.049 -0.526,-4.05 -0.645,-6.029 l 12.892,0.513 c -1.714,3.063 -2.656,9.291 -2.994,15.436"
           style="fill:#dc2b00;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12795" /><path
           d="m 506.596,634.541 -145.441,-5.777 c -0.296,-0.837 -0.584,-1.456 -0.861,-1.77 -0.541,0.316 -1.028,0.896 -1.466,1.678 l -12.892,-0.513 c -0.058,-0.955 -0.098,-1.905 -0.12,-2.853 L 467.85,561.313 Z"
           style="fill:#df5e00;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12797" /><path
           d="M 399.271,385.796 336.116,334.652 505.434,300.169 Z"
           style="fill:#68d7ef;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12799" /><path
           d="m 412.256,102.496 c 4.358,0.396 8.982,0.591 13.953,0.591 7.694,0 15.324,-0.45 22.697,-0.895 7.16,-0.424 13.921,-0.83 20.554,-0.83 h 0.007 c 1.068,0 2.103,0.015 3.124,0.037 l -54.722,66.26 z"
           style="fill:#0074d4;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12801" /><path
           d="m 467.85,561.313 -122.034,63.993 c -0.088,-3.712 0.064,-7.397 0.223,-11.243 0.299,-7.183 0.625,-15.221 -0.639,-25.194 l 9.701,-81.801 z"
           style="fill:#e88200;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12803" /><path
           d="m 299.996,417.264 c -0.756,0.553 -1.133,1.1 -1.306,1.564 -0.207,0.55 -0.412,1.138 -0.616,1.757 l -1.478,-2.243 z"
           style="fill:#dcf07d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12805" /><path
           d="m 355.101,507.068 -17.002,-25.785 c 2.359,-3.902 4.707,-7.317 6.859,-10.204 5.494,-7.379 10.473,-12.429 13.239,-15.021 -2.077,-0.509 -4.027,-0.772 -5.828,-0.772 -5.687,0 -7.945,2.554 -8.022,2.644 l -2.606,-2.008 c 11.702,-15.954 29.664,-29.914 38.349,-36.18 -2.972,-0.27 -7.276,-0.81 -12.603,-1.473 -14.018,-1.756 -33.208,-4.149 -48.197,-4.149 -4.904,0 -8.65,0.264 -11.521,0.681 l 91.502,-29.005 z"
           style="fill:#dcf07d;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12807" /><path
           d="M 336.116,334.652 263.717,234.646 c 5.562,-0.85 9.582,-1.415 11.08,-1.622 2.806,-2.753 15.877,-15.124 24.112,-15.124 h 0.007 c 0.031,-0.012 0.881,-0.418 1.858,-4.651 0.727,-3.133 1.339,-7.411 2.046,-12.371 0.656,-4.572 1.384,-9.645 2.343,-14.916 l 112.706,-18.303 z"
           style="fill:#33bded;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12809" /><path
           d="m 341.062,102.393 c 13.113,-1.604 26.603,-2.871 39.15,-2.871 8.556,0 15.948,0.567 22.594,1.731 3.02,0.531 6.16,0.944 9.45,1.243 l 5.613,65.163 z"
           style="fill:#0069d5;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12811" /><path
           d="m 305.163,185.962 c 3.201,-17.593 8.985,-37.404 23.3,-48.265 h -37.557 c -3.306,1.269 -30.29,11.454 -47.587,13.382 l 7.322,-49.721 c 5.39,0.514 10.248,2.21 14.198,4.991 2.792,1.949 7.739,2.888 15.131,2.888 10.678,0 25.282,-2.013 40.754,-4.15 6.541,-0.902 13.387,-1.845 20.338,-2.694 l 76.807,65.266 z"
           style="fill:#0382dd;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12813" /><path
           d="m 224.142,258.323 3.523,-17.392 c 13.314,-2.669 26.814,-4.872 36.052,-6.285 l 72.399,100.006 z"
           style="fill:#8cebdb;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12815" /><path
           d="m 345.4,588.869 c -0.146,-1.154 -0.309,-2.328 -0.5,-3.536 -2.786,-17.544 -5.083,-22.349 -6.015,-23.643 l -0.232,0.284 -1.183,-0.637 c -0.457,-0.244 -0.888,-0.373 -1.293,-0.373 -4.478,0 -8.531,14.236 -9.978,24.344 l -1.377,9.61 -1.865,-9.521 c -4.729,-24.137 7.237,-50.835 15.156,-68.495 0.661,-1.471 1.342,-2.99 1.991,-4.47 l 14.997,-5.364 z"
           style="fill:#f38900;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12817" /><path
           d="m 325.954,520.474 -4.825,7.481 1.833,-8.711 c 0.053,-0.249 0.11,-0.494 0.163,-0.742 l 5.513,-1.971 c -0.969,1.357 -1.877,2.692 -2.684,3.943"
           style="fill:#f38900;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12819" /><path
           d="m 336.116,334.652 63.155,51.144 -91.502,29.005 c -4.204,0.608 -6.518,1.545 -7.773,2.463 l -3.4,1.078 z"
           style="fill:#b8f3bc;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12821" /><path
           d="m 298.074,420.585 c -0.579,1.757 -1.156,3.784 -1.803,6.034 -0.031,0.109 -0.063,0.219 -0.094,0.328 l 0.419,-8.605 z"
           style="fill:#f2da4c;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12823" /><path
           d="m 340.104,512.432 c 2.048,-4.675 3.778,-8.983 3.548,-10.306 -0.096,-0.026 -0.199,-0.039 -0.315,-0.039 -3.185,0 -9.751,7.517 -14.699,14.444 l -5.513,1.971 c 3.268,-15.02 9.16,-27.606 14.974,-37.219 l 17.002,25.785 z"
           style="fill:#f2da4c;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12825" /><path
           d="m 177.26,379.209 158.856,-44.557 -39.52,83.69 z"
           style="fill:#d8f891;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12827" /><path
           d="M 224.142,258.323 336.116,334.652 177.26,379.209 Z"
           style="fill:#c5f5c2;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12829" /><path
           d="m 238.218,151.394 c -4.271,0 -7.179,-0.824 -8.878,-2.515 -1.518,-1.519 -3.184,-3.025 -4.953,-4.613 -7.81,-7.019 -16.662,-14.983 -12.088,-25.559 4.034,-9.329 20.297,-17.519 34.797,-17.519 1.204,0 2.386,0.059 3.545,0.17 l -7.322,49.721 c -1.82,0.202 -3.534,0.315 -5.101,0.315"
           style="fill:#6db0c4;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12831" /><path
           d="m 258.305,486.441 c 1.958,10.36 3.122,25.125 -3.18,34.56 -2.503,3.757 -6.536,5.738 -11.683,5.738 -8.093,0 -18.347,-5.05 -27.444,-13.51 -9.869,-9.173 -17.608,-21.525 -21.886,-34.88 -4.905,-0.042 -19.957,-1.028 -37.447,-10.41 l 20.595,-88.73 z"
           style="fill:#ffd100;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12833" /><path
           d="m 296.596,418.342 -0.419,8.605 c -4.359,15.222 -11.678,40.17 -40.357,49.189 0.6,2.017 1.62,5.732 2.485,10.305 L 177.26,379.209 Z"
           style="fill:#f9ed2f;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12835" /><path
           d="m 177.26,379.209 -3.206,-29.988 c 2.837,-0.52 4.925,-0.998 6.052,-1.415 -0.25,-1.544 0.278,-4.233 2.24,-9.489 1.621,-4.349 4.123,-10.158 7.43,-17.26 2.985,-6.413 6.118,-12.764 8.402,-17.306 l -26.734,21.051 -5.975,-55.891 c 1.081,-0.867 2.152,-1.722 3.206,-2.559 l 55.467,-8.029 z"
           style="fill:#cbf388;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12837" /><path
           d="m 168.675,266.352 c 7.006,-5.567 13.315,-10.385 17.447,-13.134 6.635,-4.408 23.923,-8.755 41.543,-12.287 l -3.523,17.392 z"
           style="fill:#97eaa3;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12839" /><path
           d="m 156.665,467.939 c -1.273,-0.682 -2.558,-1.406 -3.854,-2.18 -11.271,-6.748 -21.313,-15.942 -29.837,-27.335 -8.069,-10.798 -14.807,-23.644 -20.123,-38.301 l 74.409,-20.914 z"
           style="fill:#ffce00;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12841" /><path
           d="m 98.978,332.508 c -8.073,-9.701 -10.975,-18.495 -8.608,-26.145 3.686,-11.966 18.785,-16.392 19.422,-16.579 l 0.753,-0.212 16.301,11.374 c 3.987,-3.389 18.914,-16.048 33.381,-27.8 l -53.313,66.858 c -2.814,-2.027 -5.463,-4.525 -7.936,-7.496"
           style="fill:#f0d03e;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12843" /><path
           d="m 102.851,400.123 c -1.538,-4.24 -2.963,-8.625 -4.259,-13.165 l -0.174,-0.592 14.05,-29.76 0.933,-0.089 c 23.326,-2.174 48.682,-5.105 60.653,-7.296 l 3.206,29.988 z"
           style="fill:#f6e63c;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12845" /><path
           d="m 161.38,332.727 c -0.978,0.823 -16.43,13.741 -34.43,13.741 -7.369,0 -14.075,-2.17 -20.036,-6.464 l 53.313,-66.858 c 1.761,-1.431 3.515,-2.849 5.242,-4.235 l 5.975,55.891 z"
           style="fill:#f6e63c;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
           id="path12847" /></g></g></g></svg>
```

However, this one does not work:

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 463 463" style="enable-background:new 0 0 463 463;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path d="M455.5,103c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.5v-48c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5H7.5C3.358,40,0,43.358,0,47.5v48
        c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.5,7.5H16v177H7.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5v128c0,4.142,3.358,7.5,7.5,7.5h448c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.5
        v-128c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5H447V103H455.5z M15,55h433v33H15V55z M63,280v-17h337v17H63z M359.5,216
        c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5
        s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5
        s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5
        s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5
        s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V248H63v-49h337v49h-33v-24.5C367,219.358,363.643,216,359.5,216z M400,184h-33v-24.5
        c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5
        c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5
        c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5
        c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184h-17v-24.5
        c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V184H63v-49h337V184z M400,120H63v-17h337V120z M31,103h17v177H31V103z M288,327v81
        H175v-81H288z M416,327v81H303v-81H416z M160,408H47v-81h113V408z M448,408h-17v-88.5c0-4.142-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5h-384
        c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5V408H15V295h433V408z M432,280h-17V103h17V280z"/>
    <path d="M223.5,351h16c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.5s-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5h-16c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5S219.358,351,223.5,351z"/>
    <path d="M95.5,351h16c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.5s-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5h-16c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5S91.358,351,95.5,351z"/>
    <path d="M351.5,351h16c4.142,0,7.5-3.358,7.5-7.5s-3.358-7.5-7.5-7.5h-16c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5S347.358,351,351.5,351z"/>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I've already installed all of packages suggested in this thread: [Imagick SVG to JPG error no decode delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948471/imagick-svg-to-jpg-error-no-decode-delegate)

No success so far. However it failed to install following package: libmagick-6.q16-2

```
E: Unable to locate package libmagick-6.q16-2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libmagick-6.q16-2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libmagick-6.q16-2'
```

OS is Ubuntu 18.04

ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114

```
convert -list format | grep -i svg
     MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
      SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.4)
     SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.4)
```

Comment: I do not understand most of your error, but you are using the Imagemagick internal SVG/XML renderer, which is the least capable of 3 renderer including RSVG delegate and Inkscape. I suggest that you install Inkscape on your system in a place that Imagemagick will find it (i.e. list it it your PATH environment variable in your .profile file). You won't have to recompile Imagemagick as you would with the RSVG delegate. Imagemagick should find it and use it automatically over the internal or RSVG renderer. It is the most capable and perhaps will process that SVG file

Answer (score 0):

An SVG file needs to have this at the first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

to be properly recognized and handled by `readImageBlob()`.

Source: [readimageblob: Fatal Error when converting SVG into PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125352/readimageblob-fatal-error-when-converting-svg-into-png/15614469#15614469)